# No module named cloud while using google.cloud import bigquery

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

i have built an app engine application to load data into bigquery table using google app engine launcher but when I run it on local host or on the cloud i get the No module named cloud while using google.cloud import bigquery error message in log file. I have installed the google cloud client library but it is still giving me the same error. please see below the code I am using

---main.py file contains

```
import argparse
import time
import uuid

from google.cloud import bigquery

def load_data_from_gcs(dataset_name, table_name, source):
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
    dataset = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_name)
    table = dataset.table(table_name)
    job_name = str(uuid.uuid4())

    job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_storage(
        job_name, table, source)

    job.begin()

    wait_for_job(job)

    print('Loaded {} rows into {}:{}.'.format(
        job.output_rows, dataset_name, table_name))


def wait_for_job(job):
    while True:
        job.reload()
        if job.state == 'DONE':
            if job.error_result:
                raise RuntimeError(job.error_result)
            return
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=__doc__,
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument('Test')
    parser.add_argument('mytable')
    parser.add_argument('gs://week/geninfo.csv')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    load_data_from_gcs(
        args.dataset_name,
        args.table_name,
        args.source)
```

--app.yaml file contains the following code

```
application: mycloudproject
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

Please let me know what is missing or if I am doing something wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [app engine project to load data into bigquery not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418201/app-engine-project-to-load-data-into-bigquery-not-working)

Comment: Can you share the output of `python -v`?  This might help you see what modules you have loaded and from where.

Comment: the output has too many characters on it and doesn't allow me to post it in here. is there any other way to share my file?

Comment: hi i have managed to save the output using the pastebin and is available through this link [link](http://pastebin.com/Deh1BRQA)

Answer (score 5):

This can be a bit tricky. Google Cloud uses the new Python namespace format (if you look at the source you'll notice that there's no `__init__.py` in the directory structure).

This was changed in Python 3.3 with [PEP-420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/)

Fortunately in Python 2.7 you can fix this easily by avoiding implicit imports. Just add this to the top of your file:

`from __future__ import absolute_import`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Find the directory containing `google/cloud/...`, and add that directory to the PYTHONPATH so that python can find it. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11960602/how-to-add-something-to-pythonpath) for details on how to add to PYTHONPATH. It outlines two common ways to do it:

Here's how to do it with a bash command:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/<path_to_modules>
```

Or you could append it to the path in your script:

```
# if the google/ directory is in the directory /path/to/directory/
path_to_look_for_module = '/path/to/directory/'
import sys
if not path_to_look_for_module in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path_to_look_for_module)
```

If that doesn't work, here is some code I found in one of my projects for importing Google Appengine modules:

```
def fixup_paths(path):
    """Adds GAE SDK path to system path and appends it to the google path
    if that already exists."""
    # Not all Google packages are inside namespace packages, which means
    # there might be another non-namespace package named `google` already on
    # the path and simply appending the App Engine SDK to the path will not
    # work since the other package will get discovered and used first.
    # This emulates namespace packages by first searching if a `google` package
    # exists by importing it, and if so appending to its module search path.
    try:
        import google
        google.__path__.append("{0}/google".format(path))
    except ImportError:
        pass

    sys.path.insert(0, path)

# and then call later in your code:
fixup_paths(path_to_google_sdk)
from google.cloud import bigquery
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are trying to use the [Cloud Datastore client library](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java) in a [Google App Engine's standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments). As documented [in Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/) you should not be doing this. Instead, either use the [NDB Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/) or do not use the standard environment.

Answer (score -2):

Are you sure you've updated to the latest version of the library?  The version installed by pip may be out of date.  Previously, the module was imported as:

```
from gcloud import bigquery
```

If that works, you're running an older version.  To install the latest, I'd recommend pulling from the master in the [github project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python).

Comment: Yes, I installed the library yesterday and this still doesn't work. I have also changed the import statement to the one you have suggested from gcloud import bigquery but the it still doesn't work and giving me an error message 
ImportError: No module named gcloud