# BigQuery python client cannot be imported on GAE

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, cron, google-bigquery

I'm trying to implement a cron job on GAE which will look into a csv file in a cloud storage bucket and load that into a BigQuery table. The code works fine on my mac (macOS Sierra, 10.12.6).

However, when I am deploying the app on GAE through `gcloud app deploy app.yaml` and configuring the cron job using `gcloud app deploy cron.yaml`, the cron job fails at: 
`from google.cloud import bigquery` . I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43085047/how-to-import-bigquery-in-appengine-for-python) to no avail. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Below is the full error message from cron log.

```
Traceback (most recent call last): (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/cgi.py:122)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/f~gcp-101-181605/20171002t142145.404509292894601117/uploadBQ.py", line 17, in <module>
    from  google.cloud import bigquery
  File "/base/data/home/apps/f~gcp-101-181605/20171002t142145.404509292894601117/lib/google/cloud/bigquery/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from google.cloud.bigquery.client import Client
  File "/base/data/home/apps/f~gcp-101-181605/20171002t142145.404509292894601117/lib/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 21, in <module>
    from google.cloud.bigquery.job import CopyJob
  File "/base/data/home/apps/f~gcp-101-181605/20171002t142145.404509292894601117/lib/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py", line 34, in <module>
    import google.cloud.future.polling
  File "/base/data/home/apps/f~gcp-101-181605/20171002t142145.404509292894601117/lib/google/cloud/future/polling.py", line 23, in <module>
    import tenacity
  File "/base/data/home/apps/f~gcp-101-181605/20171002t142145.404509292894601117/lib/tenacity/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from monotonic import monotonic as now
  File "/base/data/home/apps/f~gcp-101-181605/20171002t142145.404509292894601117/lib/monotonic.py", line 41, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: No module named _ctypes
```

For reference, I am working in a virtual environment with python version 2.7.10. My `app.yaml` is:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /cronjobs
  script: uploadBQ.py
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

Content of `cron.yaml`:

```
cron:
- description: cron to BQ
  url: /cronjobs
  schedule: every 15 minutes from 10:20 to 11:20
```

Contents of requirement.txt (installed on `lib` folder through `pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib`):

```
google-api-python-client
google-cloud
```

Content of `appengine_config.py`

```
# appengine_config.py
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# Add any libraries install in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add('lib')
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this, but the stacktrace shows that `_ctypes` is being imported through a module named `tenacity`; this seems to be a recent change (and seems to have been reverted even more recently per github), so you could try try installing an older version say 0.26 or even 0.25 (current is 0.27; we use 0.22), `pip install -t lib google-cloud-bigquery==0.26` (I'd recommend completely reinstalling everything in `lib` first to ensure you get a clean install).

Comment: That did it. It was really a version issue as you said. I downgraded to version 0.19 and it is working like a charm. See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/2464 for detailed discussion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From  [BigQuery Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) (on the `PYTHON` tab):

> Installing the client library
>
> ```
> pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery
> ```

Note that the instructions are for generic python apps, I just included it for the name of the library.

So you need to add `google-cloud-bigquery` to your `requirements.txt` file, re-run the requirements installation and the app deployment on GAE.

Comment: Not working. I am getting this error `ImportError: No module named cloud` coming from  `from google.cloud import bigquery`. My new `requirements.txt` include only `google-cloud-bigquery`. On the GAE source, I can see the `/google/cloud` is present in the `lib` folder, but it still does not work. Is my path import fine: `sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "lib"))`?